# Why, in A Midsummer Night's Dream, does "square" mean "quarrel"?

Tags: etymology, shakespeare

When referring to dictionaries, there seems to be no such meaning as "quarrel" under the word "square", only "in agreement".

But in II 1 of A Midsummer Night's Dream, "square" in the following text means "quarrel":

> And now they never meet in grove, or green,
>   By fountain clear, or spangled starlight sheen,
>   But they do square, that all their elves for fear
>   Creep into acorn cups, and hide them there.

Where does this meaning come from?

Comment: A question that probably would also be well-suited for Literature SE

Comment: it's simply as in "square off for a fight".

Comment: Just BTW, I certainly wouldn't translate that as "quarrel".  That's far too soft and pansy-assed.  The sense is an all out **brawl, fist-fight, war, battle, slaughterfest**.  Nothing to do with "quarrel"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sense of to "fall out, to be at variance or discord, to disagree or quarrel" ([*OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/188195?rskey=zYV1Nq&result=6&isAdvanced=true#eid21055700), sense **8b** of **square**, *v.*; paywalled) is obsolete. It appears in historical dictionaries. *OED* attests the sense with quotes from 1542 to 1608.

Comment: Thank you. I also check the meaning of quarrel and found out that one of its meanings as a noun is "A short, heavy, square-headed arrow or bolt used in a crossbow or arbalest." And its origin is "Middle English: from Old French, based on late Latin quadrus ‘square’." I think there might be some kind of relation generated from this sense. And this kind of arrow is used around middle age, so it makes sense I guess.

Comment: @kimXU The derivation of "square" (to argue) from "quarrel" (square-headed arrow)  feels like a folk etymology to me.  Unless you have evidence of some intermediate forms I wouldn't believe it.

Comment: @kimXU strictly speaking Shakespeare was writing in the early Renaissance not the Medieval period.

Comment: @Sarriesfan More like High or Late Renaissance since it started in the 13thC and turned into The Enlightenment in the early18thC. Shakespeare was writing in the late 16th and early 17th centuries.

Comment: I feel it's confusing to describe it as "obsolete".  Any normal English speaker from today, would read it as in "squared off", which is a normal phrase you hear constantly.

Comment: @kimXU , there is *utterly* no connection to quarrel in the sense of archery.  you are piling confusion on confusion.

Comment: Even if the use was somewhat old-fashioned in Shakespeare's time, you need to remember that he needed to find a word that would fit both the meaning and the meter, since "A Midsummer Night's Dream" is in verse.

Comment: OED sense 8b may well be "obsolete", but note sense 11 - *11. 
Thesaurus »
Categories »
  
 a. To put oneself into a posture of defence; to assume a boxing attitude.
1820   J. Hogg Bridal of Polmood vi   He spit upon his hand and squared.
1823   M. M. Sherwood Henry Milner (ed. 2) iii. xvi   Then beginning to square (to use an expression of Mr. Claydon's) the enemy took to his heels.
1861   T. Hughes Tom Brown at Oxf. I. xi. 210   Selecting the one most of his own size, he squared and advanced on him.*

Comment: @WS2, in my estimation, that sense, as well as 'square off', 'square up', etc., don't answer the question of why "*in A Midsummer Night's Dream*, does 'square' mean 'quarrel'?" I have, of course, observed that some 40-odd readers disagree, but having taught Shakespeare at University level, I'm sticking to my guns.

Answer (score 43):

We actually still have versions of this usage in modern English: to [***square up***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/square-up) to or *against*<sup>1</sup> someone means (from Cambridge Dictionaries)

> to prepare to fight, compete, or argue with someone:
>   *The players squared up to each other and started shouting.*

And to [***square off***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/square-off) means (also Cambridge)

> to oppose someone in a competition or prepare to fight someone:
>   *Bradley is expected to square off with Cook in the next election.*

And a [***square go***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/square-go) is a Scottish term for (Collins Dictionary)

> a fair fight between two individuals

This "fighting" usage of *square* seems to be related to the idea of facing one's opponent [*squarely*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/squarely) (still Cambridge) and [*squaring one's shoulders*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/square%20one's%20shoulders) (Merriam-Webster) when readying oneself for an unpleasant task, as well as other square-related concepts that have to do with forthrightness and not shirking, such as [*foursquare*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foursquare) (M-W), [*on the square*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/on-the-square), and the other ways in which one can [*square up*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/square-up) (both Collins). It may also be related to the idea of two individuals being at right angles to one another.<sup>2</sup>

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/188194)<sup>1</sup> dates most of these positive senses of the word to the late 16th through the 17th century. They seem to have arisen metaphorically from the square's geometric traits: a square is upright (as opposed to any shape with non-right-angles), shows its full face (since a square seen at an angle doesn't look like a square), and is equitably arranged (since all its sides and angles are equal).

So Oberon and Titania were *squaring* in the sense that they were coming face-to-face with one another, and not edging away or sloping off from the fight.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>My impression is that the *to* version is more British (*square up to* is actually listed as a UK usage in several dictionaries) and *against* is more American (I hear *squared up against* especially in US sports contexts).</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Compare the adjective [*cross*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/44808) and the verb [*thwart*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/201601) (both OED, see note below), which both evolved from the idea of being at a right angle (to something) to, respectively, being generally angry and actively opposing someone.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>Note that the OED Online is unfortunately a prescription service (behind a paywall). However, many folks, especially in the UK, will have access through their local public library, and most students should be able to access through their institution's library. More info available at [About the OED](http://public.oed.com/about/free-oed/), including, as of February 2019, a special subscription price that is available for one more month in celebration of the OED's 90th anniversary.</sub>

Comment: Just a note that for UK based people access to the OED is likely to be free if you are a member of your local authority/university/college library. Just use your library number at Sign-in.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that a "Square go" is a common modern Scots expression for a fight. Can also be used as an expression to bait an opponent. See the following quote from Trainspotting (1996) : "When this hard cunt comes in. Obviously fuckin' fancies himself, like. Starts staring at me. Lookin' at me, right fuckin' at me, as if to say, "Come ahead, square go." " https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117951/characters/nm0001015

Comment: Is it possible "square" is related to the arena a fight or duel would take place in?

Comment: @usul given that the arenas used to be circular; eg boxing "ring", I wouldn't think it likely ... but anything is possible when it comes to language.  I'd have thought it more likely to be related to the formations of armies that would have their troops in box formation - thus if they squared off they were preparing to fight

Comment: My speculation would be that it has to do with raising the fists up, as preparation for a fight (to block or to punch), creating a roughly square shape between fists and shoulders.

Comment: I think the most likely provenance for this expression is the cited "on the square" definition (making something straight and proper, fixing it.)

Comment: Thanks, @Spagirl; I've added a note within the answer, too.

Comment: Thanks, @Smeato, I added that term. I think I'll leave the quote in the comments, though :).

Comment: @Spagirl Americans should also check to see if their local or college library has an OED subscription too. Some do, I gather. If not it may be worth a suggestion